# WinActivate on specific criteria (include / exclude windows)

Tags: autohotkey

I'm stumped on how to best re-write my hotkey. What I want to do is simple. I have a script that switches to File Explorer IF it's *currently open* Else it will *open a new file explorer window*.

Here's the catch - It's hard to "identify" if the Explorer window is open. I used to just do this by using `WinActivate, 00123456` because that's the name of the folder (eight-digit random number). But the problem with that is that these are support ticket numbers. And that number will also be within the title of my current Chrome session and sometimes other windows too (Firefox, Snagit, notepad, etc). So it will inadvertently switch to those other programs. So that led me to exclude in this way:

```
Ticket_Out := clipboard
xclude:= Ticket_Out . " | Salesforce - Google Chrome"
WinActivate, % Ticket_Out, , % xclude
```

That's handy except for it only excludes 1 window at a time. How could I implement something that excludes a second application? OR --- another thought, how could I just say: look for Explorer.exe with window title "00123456" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ahk_exe`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_exe) to filter by the process name too:

```
WinActivate, ahk_exe explorer.exe, %Ticket_Out%
```

Another way would be to look for the window class - since depending on the Windows version Explorer can use either `CabinetWClass` or `ExploreWClass`, you can use a group, as shown in the [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_group):

```
; Define the group: Windows Explorer windows
GroupAdd, Explorer, ahk_class ExploreWClass ; Unused on Vista and later
GroupAdd, Explorer, ahk_class CabinetWClass

; Activate any window matching the above criteria and the title
WinActivate, ahk_group Explorer, %Ticket_Out%
```

Answer (score 0):

Note on CherryDT's answer the two WinActivate examples are missing a comma between the *WinTitle*, and *WinText* parameters...

Should be....

```
WinActivate, ahk_exe explorer.exe, %Ticket_Out%
```

Second example (when using GroupAdd)

```
WinActivate, ahk_group Explorer, %Ticket_Out%
```

Caught me out for awhile.

(I would comment on the answer, but as a new user don't have 50 reputation)